# Allowing foreign characters in .htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, encoding

Is there a way to allow foreign characters in .htaccess mod_rewrite character sets? i.e., a way to add foreign characters like ç and others to `([A-z]+)` ?

Answer (score 2):

I’m not quite sure with what character encoding Apache interprets the data in configuration files like the .htaccess file. But you can express these characters with the hexadecimal notation `\xhh` like:

```
# ç in ISO 8859-1
RewriteRule \xE7 …
# ç in UTF-8
RewriteRule \xC3\xA7 …
```

Now all you need to know is how these characters are encoded when requested (in general either ISO 8859-1 or UTF-8).

Comment: so something like `RewriteRule /name/([A-z\xE7\xC3\xA7(and all other foreign characters allowed)]+) index.php?user=$1` ?

Comment: @ina: No, when using multi-byte characters you need to use an alternation like `([A-z\xE7]|\xC3\xA7)+)`.